# How should I refactor this method to respect the Uncle Bob rule of not having more than 2 or 3 parameters?

Tags: java, refactoring

I've got a heavy method that calculate interests of a contract based on multiple parameters. I do need each of these parameters but it's going against Uncle Bob rule of not having more than 2 or 3 parameters.

```
public double calculInteretsParPeriode(double encours, double tauxWithMarge, Date dtEch, Date dtEchPrec, boolean isFirstEcheanceInterets, Periode periodiciteK,
                                           BaseCalcul baseCalcul, TauxProportionnelOuEquivalent tauxProportionnelOuEquivalent, int tauxNDecimal,
                                           Periode periodiciteI, PeriodeCalculInterets periodeCalculInterets) {

... 

        int nMensualiteAnPlusGrand = CalculMensualite.calculNMensualiteParAnsMax(periodiciteK, periodiciteI);

        double coeffI = CalcEmprunt2014.calcCoeffInterets(
            baseCalcul.getNumerateur(),
            baseCalcul.getDenominateur(),
            dtEch,
            dtEchPrec,
            nMensualiteAnPlusGrand,
            baseCalcul.getProrata(),
            isFirstEcheanceInterets
        );

        //les intérêts sont calculés avec le taux + la marge du contrat
        switch (tauxProportionnelOuEquivalent) {
            case PROPORTIONNEL:
                return MathUtils.round2D(encours * MathUtils.arrondi(tauxWithMarge, tauxNDecimal) / 100.0 * coeffI);
            case EQUIVALENT:
                return MathUtils.round2D(encours * (Math.pow((1 + MathUtils.arrondi(tauxWithMarge, tauxNDecimal) / 100), coeffI) - 1));
            case PROPORTIONNEL_EQUIVALENT:
                return MathUtils.round2D(encours * (MathUtils.arrondi((Math.pow((1 + MathUtils.arrondi(tauxWithMarge, tauxNDecimal) / 100), coeffI) - 1) * nMensualiteAnPlusGrand, tauxNDecimal + 2) * coeffI));
            default:
                throw new GenericRuntimeException("Méthode de calcul des intérêts non pris en charge: " + tauxProportionnelOuEquivalent);
        }
}
```

I've tried using the builder pattern but it seems like cheating as I'm just moving the needed variables to class fields and still need to pass them to the builder which feels like a mess:

```
ew CalculInteretsParPeriodeBuilder()
            .withEncours(10000)
            .withTauxWithMarge(1.0)
            .withDtEch(DateCalculs.getDate(2019, Month.FEBRUARY, 1))
            .withDtEchPrec(DateCalculs.getDate(2018, Month.FEBRUARY, 1))
            .withIsFirstEcheanceInterets(false)
            .withPeriodiciteI(Periode.ANNUELLE)
            .withPeriodiciteK(Periode.ANNUELLE)
            .withTauxNDecimal(2)
            .withPeriodeCalculInterets(PeriodeCalculInterets.PAR_PERIODE)
            .withBaseCalcul(BaseCalcul.BC_360360)
            .withTauxProportionnelOuEquivalent(TauxProportionnelOuEquivalent.EQUIVALENT)
            .build()
            .calculInteretsParPeriode()
```

Comment: You can create a separate class to store the values, say, `MyCalculationParameters` class. And then just pass this one object into the method.

Comment: Their is already a "massive" object containing all needed parameters for the calculation but it's my whole "contract" and it got more than 150 fields. 
We used to just pass in the contract to all methods but it's not really convenient for some use cases like this one where this method need to be called from different context where we don't have a contract object.

Comment: true, 150 fields is quite a lot. Can't you group them together and create "sub- objects" which you then can use to call your different methods? So keep the "Contract" class but instead of `DtEch`, `DtEchPrec`, `DtEchProch`, `DtEchFin` .... you create a class `Echeances` where you put all those dates, some other related values and pass that object to your contract. The same with everything concerning `Taux` and so on.

Comment: Yes actually in all those parameters their are some of the contract in itself:
- PeriodiciteI
- PeriodiciteK
- TauxNDecimal
- PeriodeCalculInterets
- BaseCalcul
- TauxProportionnelOuEquivalent

That could be regrouped and others that are dynamic fields depending on the Echeance i'm calculating the interets. 

It's definitely something I should separate in the method, "general contract" parameters from dynamic ones

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Builder-pattern is useful when you have multiple parameters that are exchangeable (and optional). Then you can just chain them together and configure your object. But in the end they only initialize an object. So if you have say 20 parameters and your object needs always the same 10 alone to function, then putting this in the builder pattern isn't worth your while.

Let's say this is the obgligatory minimum:

```
new CalculInteretsParPeriodeBuilder()
        .withEncours(10000)
        .withTauxWithMarge(1.0)
        .withDtEch(DateCalculs.getDate(2019, Month.FEBRUARY, 1))
        .withDtEchPrec(DateCalculs.getDate(2018, Month.FEBRUARY, 1))
        .withIsFirstEcheanceInterets(false);
```

Then just calling a constructor is shorter:

```
CalculInteretsParameters params = new CalculInteretsParameters(
        10000,
        1.0,
        DateCalculs.getDate(2019, Month.FEBRUARY, 1),
        DateCalculs.getDate(2018, Month.FEBRUARY, 1),
        false
);
```

And in my opinion there is nothing wrong with some simple `setter` calls for all the optional parameters:

```
 params.setPeriodiciteI(Periode.ANNUELLE);
 params.setPeriodiciteK(Periode.ANNUELLE);

 if(reallyNecessary){           // see? way more dynamic :)
     params.setTauxNDecimal(2);
     params.setPeriodeCalculInterets(PeriodeCalculInterets.PAR_PERIODE);
 }else{
     params.setBaseCalcul(BaseCalcul.BC_360360);
 }
```

In your case I wouldn't use it. Just initialize a parameter object (as dynamic as you want and need it to) and pass it to the calculation method.

**EDIT**

Sorry, to actually answer your question I would go with a parameter class:

```
 CalculInteretsParameters params = new CalculInteretsParameters();
 params.setTauxWithMarge(1.0);  //  set all your dates, numbers and parameters
 params.setPeriodicite(2);
 ...

 // then call your method (maybe even with some dynamic values)
 calculInteretsParPeriode(params, someDynamicValue);
```

Comment: So I should just shift the problem of passing all those parameters from my actual method `calculInteretsParPeriode` to an container object `CalculInteretsParameters` ? And to build this container with all parameters use a Factory or a Builder pattern ? It just feels like I'm going around the problem and not facing it. I can't see any other/better way of doing it though.. 
How is it better to user a parameter class instead of passing all the parameters directly to the method ?

Comment: you can reuse the parameter class. or better the parameter object. Recalculate and update its values and then just continue. No need to return it from your calculation methods or passing all of the parameters again to other methods. But I don't think there is a general rule you can apply to "clean up" your method calls. And if there is a specific method that really really needs 50 parameters to function, well then this wouldn't be the end of everything. As long as not all your methods have so many parameters and as long as you don't pass along values you don't need.

Comment: Separating general parameters from dynamic ones is a good idea that I should try implementing. 

Maybe using a BuilderPattern with a constructor containing all general parameters and adding the dynamic parameters with setters.

Answer (score 1):

Small follow-up to show some code, I ended up doing exactly what @GameDroids recommanded using a Builder for the "general" parameters and having more "specific" parameters in the signature of the calcul() method.

```
public class CalculInteretsParPeriodeBuilder {
    private ContratBasic contratBasic;
    private DefinitionTaux contratTaux;
    private Periode periodiciteK;
    private Periode periodiciteI;
    private BaseCalcul baseCalcul;
    private TauxProportionnelOuEquivalent tauxProportionnelOuEquivalent;
    private Integer tauxNDecimal;
    private PeriodeCalculInterets periodeCalculInterets = PeriodeCalculInterets.PAR_PERIODE;

    public CalculInteretsParPeriodeBuilder withContratBasic(ContratBasic contratBasic) {
        this.contratBasic = contratBasic;
        return this;
    }

    public CalculInteretsParPeriodeBuilder withContratTaux(DefinitionTaux contratTaux) {
        this.contratTaux = contratTaux;
        return this;
    }

    public CalculInteretsParPeriodeBuilder withPeriodiciteK(Periode periodiciteK) {
        this.periodiciteK = periodiciteK;
        return this;
    }

    public CalculInteretsParPeriodeBuilder withBaseCalcul(BaseCalcul baseCalcul) {
        this.baseCalcul = baseCalcul;
        return this;
    }

    public CalculInteretsParPeriodeBuilder withBaseCalcul(com.dev1.seldon.infodette.beans.contrat2014.commons.enums.BaseCalcul baseCalcul) {
        this.baseCalcul = new BaseCalcul(baseCalcul);
        return this;
    }

    public CalculInteretsParPeriodeBuilder withTauxProportionnelOuEquivalent(TauxProportionnelOuEquivalent tauxProportionnelOuEquivalent) {
        this.tauxProportionnelOuEquivalent = tauxProportionnelOuEquivalent;
        return this;
    }

    public CalculInteretsParPeriodeBuilder withTauxNDecimal(int tauxNDecimal) {
        this.tauxNDecimal = tauxNDecimal;
        return this;
    }

    public CalculInteretsParPeriodeBuilder withPeriodiciteI(Periode periodiciteI) {
        this.periodiciteI = periodiciteI;
        return this;
    }

    public CalculInteretsParPeriodeBuilder withPeriodeCalculInterets(PeriodeCalculInterets periodeCalculInterets) {
        this.periodeCalculInterets = periodeCalculInterets;
        return this;
    }

    public CalculInteretsParPeriode build() {

        if (contratBasic != null && contratTaux != null) {
            this.periodiciteK = contratBasic.getPeriodiciteK();
            this.periodiciteI = contratTaux.getPeriodiciteI();
            this.baseCalcul = contratTaux.getBaseCalculI();
            this.tauxProportionnelOuEquivalent = contratTaux.getTauxProportionnelOuEquivalent();
            this.tauxNDecimal = contratTaux.getTauxNDecimal();
            this.periodeCalculInterets = contratTaux.getPeriodeCalculInteret();
        }

        if (periodiciteK == null) throw new MandatoryMethodParameterException("periodiciteK");
        if (baseCalcul == null) throw new MandatoryMethodParameterException("baseCalcul");
        if (tauxProportionnelOuEquivalent == null) throw new MandatoryMethodParameterException("tauxProportionnelOuEquivalent");
        if (tauxNDecimal == null) throw new MandatoryMethodParameterException("tauxNDecimal");
        if (periodiciteI == null) throw new MandatoryMethodParameterException("periodiciteI");

        return new CalculInteretsParPeriode(periodiciteK, baseCalcul, tauxProportionnelOuEquivalent, tauxNDecimal, periodiciteI, periodeCalculInterets);
    }
}
```

And

```
public class CalculInteretsParPeriode {

    private PeriodeCalculInterets periodeCalculInterets;
    private Periode periodiciteI;
    private Periode periodiciteK;
    private TauxProportionnelOuEquivalent tauxProportionnelOuEquivalent;
    private int tauxNDecimal;
    private BaseCalcul baseCalcul;

    public CalculInteretsParPeriode(Periode periodiciteK, BaseCalcul baseCalcul, TauxProportionnelOuEquivalent tauxProportionnelOuEquivalent, int tauxNDecimal,
                                    Periode periodiciteI, PeriodeCalculInterets periodeCalculInterets) {
        this.periodiciteK = periodiciteK;
        this.periodiciteI = periodiciteI;
        this.baseCalcul = baseCalcul;
        this.tauxProportionnelOuEquivalent = tauxProportionnelOuEquivalent;
        this.tauxNDecimal = tauxNDecimal;
        this.periodeCalculInterets = periodeCalculInterets;
    }

    public double calculInteretsParPeriode(double encours, double tauxWithMarge, Date dtEch, Date dtEchPrec, boolean isFirstEcheanceInterets) {

        if (dtEch == null) throw new MandatoryMethodParameterException("dtEch");
        if (dtEchPrec == null) throw new MandatoryMethodParameterException("dtEchPrec");

        int nMensualiteAnPlusGrand = CalculMensualite.calculNMensualiteParAnsMax(periodiciteK, periodiciteI);

        double coeffI = CalcEmprunt2014.calcCoeffInterets(
            baseCalcul.getNumerateur(),
            baseCalcul.getDenominateur(),
            dtEch,
            dtEchPrec,
            nMensualiteAnPlusGrand,
            baseCalcul.getProrata(),
            isFirstEcheanceInterets
        );

        return MathUtils.round2D(encours * MathUtils.arrondi(tauxWithMarge, tauxNDecimal) / 100.0 * coeffI);

    }

}
```

So thank's a lot